# Personalizar saída de consulta SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Como faço para personalizar uma saída de uma consulta SQL exemplo resultado de uma soma das colunas SAÍDA: 23000 queria personalizar apenas essa saída para R$ 23.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`TO_CHAR(number)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions189.htm#SQLRF06130) passando os valores corretos para o parâmetro: `fmt`.

**Syntax:**

`TO_CHAR(n [, fmt [, 'nlsparam' ] ])`

**Exemplo, com decimal:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(23000,'L99G999D99') FROM DUAL;
```

Saída:              `R$23.000,00`

**Exemplo, sem decimal:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(23000,'L99G999') FROM DUAL;
```

Saída:             `R$23.000`

---

**Explicando:**

`fmt`: Deve ser o formato desejado para a conversão, pode ver todas as opções [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm), onde:

- `L`: Retorna o símbolo da moeda setado para seu banco ([`NLS_CURRENCY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options065.htm#OLADM406)).
- `G`: Retorna o separador de grupo setado para seu banco ([`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options072.htm#OLADM413)).
- `D`: Retorna o separador de decimal setado para seu banco ([`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options072.htm#OLADM413)).

Lembrando, que o número `9` presente no formato, refere-se a quantidade de dígitos que sua mascará comparta, neste caso, o valor máximo será:          `R$99.999,99` com decimal e `R$99.999` sem decimal.

---

### Update:

Caso seu banco de dados esteja configurado com um padrão diferente do que deseja, é possível alterar o valor das propriedades `NLS_CURRENCY` e `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER` diretamente no `TO_CHAR`, utilizando o parâmetro `nlsparam`, exemplo:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(23000,'L99G999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' NLS_CURRENCY = ''R$'' ') FROM DUAL;
```

Como pode ver neste [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33705/1) o padrão do *SQL Fiddle* é americano e neste outro [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33705/4), alterando os parâmetros para o padrão que deseja.

Comment: Obrigado Henrique consegui aqui.